# Why did a Moq-mocked method return null?

Tags: null, moq

When I try to use my mocked `GetProfileFromUserName` method, it returns `null`. A similar method named `GetEmail` works.

This is the code for retrieving the profile, which doesn't work:

```
mockUserRepository.Setup(gp => gp.GetProfileFromUserName(userProfile.UserName))
                  .Returns(new Profile { ProfileID = userProfile.ProfileID });
```

And this is the code for retrieving the email, which works.

```
mockUserRepository.Setup(em => em.GetEmail(new MockIdentity("JohnDoe").Name))
                  .Returns("johndoe@gmail.com");
```

And this is a snippet of the method the mock calls and returns null on instead of a profile:

```
public ActionResult ShowProfile()
    {
        var profile = _userRepository.GetProfileFromUserName(User.Identity.Name);
```

What am i doing wrong?

If i replace the userProfile.UserName in the GetProfileFromUserName to It.IsAny();

Comment: What happens if you use `It.IsAny<string>()`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If it returns null, it means that your `Setup` didn't match the actual call. Check that the `userProfile.UserName` contains the correct value **at the Setup line**.

Also, to detect the unmatched calls create your `mockUserRepository` with the `MockBehavior.Strict` option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It happened to me that I was using an implicit cast operator so the method compiled but moq did not match the call.

Comment: In my case I used this `It.IsAny<long>()` instead of sending a different values during mock setup, which was not matching earlier and returned null. Now it got fixed.

Answer (score 11):

In my case the mistake was initializing the object with a wrong signature even the code was compiled:

**Wrong** (The parameter type is **int**):

```
_mockEntityServices.Setup(x => x.GetEntities(It.IsAny<int>()))
                   .Returns(new List<Entity>());
```

**Correct** (The parameter type is **int?**):

```
_mockEntityServices.Setup(x => x.GetEntities(It.IsAny<int?>()))
                   .Returns(new List<Entity>());
```

**Mocked method's signature:**

```
public IList<Entity> GetEntities(int? parentEntityId)
```

Comment: OMG! Thanks for pointing this out.. I had similar issue and was literally going mad for not able to identify the cause :D

Comment: In my case I swapped `long` for `int`. Hard to spot

Comment: Thank you very much! In my case the real method expected IEnumerable<T> and I was mocking it passing List<T>... the mock was always returning null even though the code compiled. Problem solved. :D

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who is trying to return an object, that does not exist at the time of the test setup ("Arrange"), the solution is to use the delegate (Func<>) overload:

```
mockUserRepository.Setup(gp => gp.GetProfileFromUserName(userProfile.UserName))
     .Returns(() => new Profile { ProfileID = userProfile.ProfileID });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a class type object passed as parameter to the moq method. So I used

```
mymockprovider.Setup(m=> m.getsomething(It.IsAny<myclasstype>())).Returns(testdata)
```

Comment: Can you clarify the distinction between this suggestion and [@Karr's previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53649215/3025856), which covers the same basic pattern?

Comment: Hi , Karr is talking about his experience with difference in signature while I faced an issue where I was passing new objects to the method which was passing null instead of object. I tried above method of passing It.IsAny<class>() instead of new class() and it magically started creating mock object and worked fine.